# Error: Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, encryption

I am stuck with an encryption method. I don't have very much knowledge on encryption or Byte array so its been difficult to me to solve this issue.

Here is my Code:

```
 public static class EncryptDecrypt {
    private static byte[] key = { };
    private static string sEncryptionKey = "B@|@j!";
    private static byte[] IV = {0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, 0x90, 0xab};

public static string Encrypt(string stringToEncrypt)
    {
        string returnstring = "";
        try
        {

            key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sEncryptionKey);
            DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
            System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms,
                des.CreateEncryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();

            returnstring = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

            //URL Encryption Avoid Reserved Characters
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("/", "-2F-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("!", "-21-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("#", "-23-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("$", "-24-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("&", "-26-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("'", "-27-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("(", "-28-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace(")", "-29-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("*", "-2A-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("+", "-2B-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace(",", "-2C-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace(":", "-3A-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace(";", "-3B-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("=", "-3D-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("?", "-3F-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("@", "-40-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("[", "-5B-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("]", "-5D-");


            return returnstring;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

But whenever I passed a string as `string encrypt= EncryptDecrypt.Encrypt("abcd");` It provides an error Specified key is not a valid size for this algorithm.
How to solve this problem and how could I able to encrypt any string (mostly 1-8 character) though this method?

Comment: _"How to solve this problem"_ -- based on the error message, seems like you ought to provide a key value that _is_ a valid size for the algorithm. Barring that, fix your question so that you've included a good [mcve] that reproduces the problem and explain why it is you think that the value you're using for `sEncryptionKey` should work.

Comment: Base 64 only contains the special characters `+`, `/` and `=`.  So there is no need to replace any other characters. If you do replace them you'd better off using [base 64 url](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#page-7). A password is not the same thing as a key and use DES is of course nice if you live in the year 1970. Try AES-GCM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DES algorithm expects 64-bit (8 bytes) key. Your `sEncryptionKey` has length of 6 chars, that's why you get "Specified key is not a valid size" error.

DES works with 64-bit keys and these keys should not be human-friendly passprases like 'SomePass'. They should be binary keys that cover all possible variety for 64-bit keys (2^64 different combinations). Otherwise your encryption will be much more weaker than DES standard implies.

That's why when using symmetric encryption algorithms from `System.Security.Cryptography`, you should treat your secret not as final key that will be used for encryption but as a passphrase from which you generate encryption key. You perform this generation by constructing instance of `System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes` with your passprase and some salt (which could be randomly generated but should also be used during decryption).

Another problem with your code is that you're using initialization vector (`IV`) with 6 bytes length. It should also be 8-bytes length and you should use **random** initialization vector for each encryption. You could generate IV by calling `DESCryptoServiceProvider.GenerateIV()` method and accessing `DESCryptoServiceProvider.IV` property.

And final note. Since you convert `returnstring` to Base64 there is no need in replacing all those special characters, like '&' and '$'. Base64 charset consists from digits, numbers and '+', '/', '=' symbols. You could replace only these 3 chars.

So here is edit of your code based on above comments:

```
public static class EncryptDecrypt
{
    private static string sEncryptionPassphrase = "B@|@j!";

    public static string Encrypt(string stringToEncrypt)
    {
        try
        {
            string returnstring;
            var salt = GenerateSalt();
            using (var keyBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sEncryptionPassphrase, salt))
            {
                var key = keyBytes.GetBytes(8);

                DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                des.GenerateIV();
                byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
                System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(key, des.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                returnstring = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            }

            //URL Encryption Avoid Reserved Characters
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("/", "-2F-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("+", "-2B-");
            returnstring = returnstring.Replace("=", "-3D-");

            return returnstring;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }

    private static byte[] GenerateSalt()
    {
        var randomBytes = new byte[8];
        using (var rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rngCsp.GetBytes(randomBytes);
        }
        return randomBytes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your very good explanation :) It helps lot to understand cryptography...

Comment: could you please tell how to decrypt string in your way